# Implementing an RTMP server

Tags: flash, video, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I need to create an RTMP server, in .NET.
The purpose of the server is to fetch video from IP cameras and act as an RTMP server so that an RTMP client (it will be a web client) will be able to retrieve the video by connecting to rtmp://server_address....

I would of course rather use an existing package, over implementing the whole protocol on my own.

What are the best options?

Comment: Did you consider using existing media servers like Wowza or Red5?

Comment: Yes, I was considering that and technically this is probably a good solution. But the business model I'm working under does not allow that.